# Why is typecasting between to different structure pointers feasible?

Tags: c, pointers, xcb

This code snippet is copied from the [last tutorial example of the events in XCB](http://xcb.freedesktop.org/tutorial/events/):

```
01    xcb_generic_event_t *event;
02    while ( (event = xcb_wait_for_event (connection)) ) {
03        switch (event->response_type & ~0x80) {
04        case XCB_EXPOSE: {
05            xcb_expose_event_t *expose = (xcb_expose_event_t *)event;
06            printf ("Window %"PRIu32" exposed. Region to be redrawn at location (%"PRIu16",%"PRIu16"), with dimension (%"PRIu16",%"PRIu16")\n",
07                    expose->window, expose->x, expose->y, expose->width, expose->height );
08            break;
09        }
```

In the 5th line, pointer to [`xcb_generic_event_t`](http://xcb.freedesktop.org/manual/structxcb__generic__event__t.html) is typecasted to pointer to [`xcb_expose_event_t`](http://xcb.freedesktop.org/manual/structxcb__expose__event__t.html), is it a good way to do such an operation in standard C language? And please explain what is the meaning of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's *feasible* because both structures start with the same few members.

I haven't used xcb, but just looking at the code using it I presume that `xcb_wait_for_event()`, which returns a pointer to an `xcb_generic_event_t` object, in this case returns a pointer that actually points to an `xcb_expose_event_t` event. The former is, as the name implies, a "generic" type that can be used as a placeholder for any of several more specific types. The first few members (including the `response_type` member) are shared, in the sense that they have the same size and are stored at the same offset in both structure types. Thus the code can safely refer to the `response_type` member of an `xcb_generic_event_t` object, and based on that infer that the object is really an `xcb_expose_event_t` object. The pointer cast allows the code to reinterpret the object as an `xcb_expose_event_t` object.

Looking at the linked definitions of the two types, I see that `xcb_generic_event_t` actually has 5 members, and only the first 3 are shared with `xcb_expose_event_t`. This is unlikely to cause problems as long as the code doesn't refer to the final 2 members of the `xcb_generic_event_t`.

And the C standard makes a special guarantee that covers this case. Quoting [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.5.3.2, paragraph 6:

> One special guarantee is made in order to simplify the use of unions:
>   if a union contains several structures that share a common initial
>   sequence (see below), and if the union object currently contains one
>   of these structures, it is permitted to inspect the common initial
>   part of any of them anywhere that a declaration of the completed type
>   of the union is visible. Two structures share a *common initial
>   sequence* if corresponding members have compatible types (and, for
>   bit-fields, the same widths) for a sequence of one or more initial
>   members.

Strictly speaking, this applies only when the two structures are members of a union. But the easiest way for a C compiler to satisfy this guarantee is to give all structures with a common initial subsequence the same layout for that subsequence. The behavior if the code in the question might not be 100% well defined, but in practice it's reasonably certain to be safe. (It's conceivable that an aggressive optimizing compiler might perform some transformation that causes the code to misbehave, but such an optimization would break a lot of existing code, something compiler implementers are highly motivated to avoid.)

Answer (score 2):

From *The C programming language - Second edition*

**A.8.3 Structure and Union Declarations**

> If a pointer to a structure is cast to the type of a pointer to its
>   first member, the result refers to the first member.

But in this case `xcb_expose_event_t` is defined as

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t      response_type; /* The type of the event, here it is XCB_EXPOSE */
    uint8_t      pad0;
    uint16_t     sequence;
    xcb_window_t window;        /* The Id of the window that receives the event (in case */
                                /* our application registered for events on several windows */
    uint16_t     x;             /* The x coordinate of the top-left part of the window that needs to be redrawn */
    uint16_t     y;             /* The y coordinate of the top-left part of the window that needs to be redrawn */
    uint16_t     width;         /* The width of the part of the window that needs to be redrawn */
    uint16_t     height;        /* The height of the part of the window that needs to be redrawn */
    uint16_t     count;
} xcb_expose_event_t;
```

As you can see, the first member of the `struct` is not defined as `xcb_generic_event_t`, seems undefined behavior to me.

Comment: Yes, UB is what I'm concerned about in this XCB structure definition.